# Jest with custom function that sets some pre condition and execution order

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to extend Jest to easier get API integration tests to play along between different APIs.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/01/30/jest-add-custom-functions/) and I have it working somewhat. Here's my setup:

`jest.setup.api.ts`

```
test.apiOne = async (
    name: string,
    fn?: jest.ProvidesCallback,
    timeout?: number
  ) => {
    console.log(`Running test "${name}" against API 1`)
    pactum.request.setBaseUrl(`${process.env.API_TEST_HOST}/one`)
    test(name, fn, timeout)
}

test.apiTwo = async (
    name: string,
    fn?: jest.ProvidesCallback,
    timeout?: number
  ) => {
    console.log(`Running test "${name}" against API 2`)
    pactum.request.setBaseUrl(`${process.env.API_TEST_HOST}/two`)
    test(name, fn, timeout)
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
test.apiOne("1", async () => {
    console.log("1");
})

test.apiTwo("2", async () => {
    console.log("2");
})

test.apiOne("3", async () => {
    console.log("3");
})

test.apiOne("4", async () => {
    console.log("4");
})
```

When I run these tests, this is the output

```
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "1" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "2" against API 2
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "3" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "4" against API 2
console.log mytest.ts:511
    1

console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "1" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "2" against API 2
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "3" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "4" against API 2
console.log mytest.ts:511
    2

console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "1" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "2" against API 2
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "3" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "4" against API 2
console.log mytest.ts:511
    3

console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "1" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "2" against API 2
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:26
    Running test "3" against API 1
console.log jest.setup.api.ts:38
    Running test "4" against API 2
console.log mytest.ts:511
    4
```

So for all tests it is always the conditions for the last test within the describe that gets set. So test `1` should run against API path `/one` but actually gets run against `/two`.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying do with Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is wrong on some points.

Modifying third-party API for your own needs isn't a good practice. If there's a need for custom test helpers, there's no need to modify `test`. They can be importable or global and be used the same way as `test.apiOne` but with less potential problems. It's a mistake to make these functions `async`. Tests should be known at the time when test run starts, so `async` results in a promise that isn't used. The article uses `await` yet types a function to return `void`.

`test.apiOne` cannot contain asynchronous operations, they will be discarded when they occur after `test(...)` and they will result in missing test when they occur before. `test(...)` result isn't returned, this means that a promise it returns won't be handled correctly by Jest.

`` console.log(`Running test "${name}" against API 1`) `` mistakenly suggests that it's called when a test runs, but it's actually called when it's declared.

`pactum.request.setBaseUrl` should be called inside a test it's supposed to affect. Considering that tests are asynchronous and use promises and not `done` callback, a helper is:

```
global.testApiOne = (name, fn, timeout) => {
  test(
    name, 
    async () => {
      console.log(`Running test "${name}" against API 1`)
      pactum.request.setBaseUrl(`${process.env.API_TEST_HOST}/one`)
      await fn();
    },
    timeout
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves my issue and I understand the problems with my current approach. Got it working using js, now just fighting a bit with typescript to get it working with types too.